# vector with characters displaying

Tags: c++, arrays, string, io, formatting

I have a problem with displaying the data entered in register. The folowing program that I wrote displays just the last register.( ziua=day , inregistrari=registers, data=date (ex. 03.02.2013))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char ziua[30],data[30],inregistrari[90];
    int n,i;
    cout<<"INPUT DATA"<<endl;
    system("Pause");
    cout<<"\nEnter the day in which you want to perform the register: ";
    cin>>ziua;
    cout<<"\nDATE:";
    cin>>data;
    cout<<"\nEnter the number of registers you wanna perfom for the day "<<ziua<<":";
    cin>>n;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"\nRegister "<<i<<":";
        gets(inregistrari);
    }
    cout<<"The data for the day of "<<ziua<<" are the following: ";
    cout<<"\nDATE: "<<data;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    cout<<"\n"<<inregistrari;
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. you are programming in C++, you should use `std::string` instead of C-style strings.
2. `inregistrari[90]` is an array of characters big enough to hold 1 string of max length of 89 `char`s (+ terminating character), but your loop seems to be treating it as an array or strings (although in this case `gets(inregistrari);` keeps on rewriting the same string)
3. function `gets` is generally deprecated, in C you should use `fgets` instead (yet this is C++, thus the real solution here should be using `std::getline`)
4. instead of C-style arrays, use `std::vector<std::string>` here.
5. printing the `inregistrari` is in the body of `for` loop, but each iteration of this loop does exactly the same thing (the printing does not depend on `i` in any way)
6. `using namespace std;` within the global space is a bad practice
7. you don't have to declare all variables at the beginning of the function, this was necessary in old ANSI C (about 20 years ago)

Here's an example how it could look like instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string day, date;
    int registerCount;

    std::cout << "INPUT DATA"
              << std::endl << std::endl
              << "Enter the day in which you want to perform the register: "
              << std::endl;
    std::cin >> day;
    std::cout << "DATE:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> date;
    std::cout << "Enter the number of registers you wanna perfom for the day "
              << day << ":" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> registerCount;

    std::vector<std::string> registers(registerCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < registerCount; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Register " << i << ":" << std::endl;
        std::getline(std::cin, registers[i]);
    }

    std::cout << "The data for the day of " << day << " are the following: "
              << std::endl;

    std::cout << "DATE: " << date << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < registerCount; ++i)
        std::cout << registers[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Note that you might wrap `std::getline(std::cin, registers[i])` with `if` statement and check whether a valid stream object has been return and in case of empty lines, it will read the empty string thus you might also make sure that `!registers[i].empty()`.

Comment: So what should I do in order to write in a separate array every register ?

Comment: @CokeThe: Give me second, I'll write it for you :)

Comment: my compilator doesn't recognize the variables if I don't declare them

Comment: @CokeThe: Out of pure curiosity: what exactly is the compiler you're using? Btw check my answer now, I also added some additional info about `std::getline`

Comment: devcplusplus compiler

Comment: I applied rule 7 to the vector for you :/ Also, I'd consider making `int` into `size_t` and adding some stream state checks on `std::cin`. In fairness that's beyond the scope of this question

Comment: @sehe: Delaying the construction of vector after the reading of its size was a neat edit indeed. I was not paying enough of attention while rewriting the original code :)

Comment: Could you tell me what is this line meaning ?   std::vector<std::string> registers(registerCount);

Comment: @CokeThe: Constructs the object of type `std::vector<std::string>` named `registers`. After the vector is constructed, it will hold `registerCount` empty strings in it.

Comment: Could you tell me how to eliminate the Register 0 before the reading of registers starts ? if you run the program when the user is asked how many registers (and for example he gives the number 4) it will start like this : Register 0 and then the user will be able to write on Register 1 if you understand what I meant ....

Comment: @CokeThe: I don't understand you, but if you are experiencing another problem, you can try to create a new question :) Just make sure you will describe your problem properly so that people can help you :)

Comment: it's a problem on that for i think but i don't know where...when the computer asks for registers it appears register 0 but you can't write on register 0 just on register 1